# What's the largest universe we use?

Tags: category-theory

I know that the notion of a Grothendieck universe is used to deal with the fact that sometimes the categories of category theory are "too large". In general, how large of a universe is worked in?

If I say $U_1$ is the Grothendieck universe containing all the usual sets, and $U_2$ is the smallest universe containing $U_1$, and similar for general $U_n$, then how far up do we go?

Comment: The Von Neumann universe is quite large.

Comment: @wythagoras Is that generally used, though?

Comment: With the construction you gave, shouldn't $U_2=U_1$?

Comment: Containing the first universe as an element, is what I think I meant, can't check quite now but I'll give a better look later

Comment: Sometimes I'm lazy and I prove theorems for categories in $U_n$ using categories in $U_{n+1}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Well, in retrospect, that's probably the best way to do things. I guess to know the truth you'd basically have to analyse every categorical theorem - thanks 

Comment: As I experieced thus far, one rarely has to leave $U_2$.

Comment: @Berci Rarely? When might you leave?